# Tratar erro de um método chamado por uma go routine

Tags: golang

Quando temos um método como esse:

```
func (vu *VideoUpload) ProcessUpload(concurrency int, doneUpload chan string) error {
    in := make(chan int, runtime.NumCPU())
    returnChannel := make(chan string)

    err := vu.loadPaths()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    uploadClient, ctx, err := getClientUpload()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    for process := 0; process < concurrency; process++ {
        go vu.uploadWorker(in, returnChannel, uploadClient, ctx)
    }

    go func() {
        for x:= 0; x < len(vu.Paths); x++ {
            in <- x
        }
        close(in)
    }()

    for r := range returnChannel {
        if r != "" {
            doneUpload <- r
            break
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Mas ele é chamado por uma go routine:

```
go videoUpload.ProcessUpload(concurrency, doneUpload)
```

Como podemos tratar esse erro? Pois normalmente fazemos:

```
err := vu.loadPaths()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Comment: Posso falar por mim, geralmente o que eu faço é colocar uma chamada para alguma base de logs, onde eu posso verificar os dados em um segundo momento. Creio que a maneira golang de tratar esse fluxo seria utilizando channels para comunicar entre processos. Porém nunca utilizei essa funcionalidade da linguagem. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Você poder usar o pacote https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup e criar algo nesse sentido:

```golang
func main() {
    var g errgroup.Group

    g.Go(func() error {
        return vu.ProccessUpload(0, make(chan string, 0))
    })

    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func (vu *VideoUpload) ProcessUpload(concurrency int, doneUpload chan string) error {
    in := make(chan int, runtime.NumCPU())
    returnChannel := make(chan string)

    err := vu.loadPaths()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    uploadClient, ctx, err := getClientUpload()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    for process := 0; process < concurrency; process++ {
        go vu.uploadWorker(in, returnChannel, uploadClient, ctx)
    }

    go func() {
        for x:= 0; x < len(vu.Paths); x++ {
            in <- x
        }
        close(in)
    }()

    for r := range returnChannel {
        if r != "" {
            doneUpload <- r
            break
        }
    }
```

Se você precisa que a execução não seja blockante, você pode inserir o tratamento do `g.Wait()` dentro de uma goroutine também.

Outra opção seria usar um canal conforme sugerido pelo @Danizavtz, seguindo exatamento o mesmo fluxo do errgroup.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o jeito mais fácil seria criar um channel de error handler, enviar as mensagens de erro para que sejam tratadas como devem ser (Pode ser usado um sistema de Tags para separá-las por contexto), e seguir com a aplicação ou finalizá-la dependendo do erro gerado